# Take a single picture using webcam in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigator

I am making a small class in javascript to use a webcam for an electron and cylon application. They need to use the camera like a digital camera, as in, see the video stream, click a button, and save that image.

```
class Camera {
  constructor() {
    this.video = document.createElement('video');
  }
  getStream() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
  streamTo(stream, element) {
    var video = this.video;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      element.appendChild(video);
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
        video.play();
        resolve(video);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This will allow me to make a stream and append the stream to the page as a video element. However, my question is: how can I get a single picture from this stream? Eg, on some sort of button click, save the current frame.

```
$('button[data-action="take-picture"]').on('click', function (ev) {
  // the clicked button has a "source" referencing the video.
  var video = $(ev.target).data('source');
  // lost here. Want to catch current "state" of the video.
  // take that still image and put it in the "target" div to preview.
  $(ev.target).data('target').append( /** my image here */ );
});
```

How can I save a picture from a video stream in javascript on an event?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos (Too long to put in an answer).

Comment: awesome! Not sure why I couldn't find that one on google, from mozilla too

Comment: But remember that this will only work on a few browsers. Some don;t support this feature. I just Googled "html5 webcam api take picture"

Comment: second that; I had to do a similar thing for a recent project and got all I needed off that MDN tutorial and then following the doc links from there.

Comment: In this case, wide browser compatibility is not of huge concern because it should only be on electron

Comment: corvid since the answer would really be too long to prevent you from being closed (i need this in the future and will use it as a reference) go ahead and answer it yourself.. or @putvande if you think you are ok with doing something similar idc which.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link @putvande supplied, I was able to create the following in my class. I added a canvas to the constructor to make it work. Sorry for the long code block though.

```
class Camera {
  constructor(video, canvas, height=320, width=320) {
    this.isStreaming = false;  // maintain the state of streaming
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    // need a canvas and a video in order to make this work.
    this.canvas = canvas || $(document.createElement('canvas'));
    this.video = video || $(document.createElement('video'));
  }

  // streamTo and getStream are more or less the same.

  // returns a new image element with a still shot of the video as streaming.
  takePicture() {
    let image = new Image();
    let canv = this.canvas.get(0)
    var context = canv.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(this.video.get(0), 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    var data = canv.toDataUrl('image/png');
    image.src = data;
    return image;
  }
}
```